# Playframework 2.1.0 Apache 2 Deployment CentOS 6

Tags: linux, apache, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.1

I've developed an web application with Playframework 2.1 and I want to deploy it in a VPS with only 128MB of RAM Memory. I was hopping that I could use the same VPS to other web sites (using Apache 2) but I don't know how to do this. I have the play project and another web site using only html to deploy on the same VPS. Like I said in the title, I'm using CentOS 6 (but I can use other OS if it is best, like Ubuntu).

In other words, I need help to configure Virtual Servers, proxys, etc. to different web sites in the same machine. I've already looked at Play Documentation but it's not enough.... If someone could help I would be appreciated.

Thanks